# My validation method is not working, where am i going wrong?

Tags: java

The purpose of the following method should check the input by the user such that it matches a value from the arrayList contained within the seriesLibrary object. It is currently failing to do so and keeps outputting the else option despite if a value is in the arrayList

```
public static String checkUserInputSeriesName(Scanner sc, SeriesLibrary seriesLibrary){
    boolean validInput = false;
    String seriesName = null;
    do{
        validInput = false;
        seriesName=sc.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < seriesLibrary.getTvSeries().size(); i++){
            if(seriesName.equals(seriesLibrary.getTvSeries().get(i))){
                validInput = true;
            }else{
                System.out.println("That Series does not exist, please try again!");
                sc.nextLine();
            }
        }   
    }while(!validInput);
    return seriesName;
}
```

Comment: Can you put the SeriesLibrary seriesLibrary parameter that you are passing ? Because that is an object and not a list or an array of objects.

Comment: just run your code step by step, and you'll see what happens

Comment: @dur Like i said in a comment, i realise that the else statement is currently the issue, but i am not sure where to go from there

Comment: Can you check if it's a case problem by giving `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals`? and the else part should be out of the for loop cause you are just looking at the first item and then moving to the else case if it fails

Comment: @njzk2 i have realised the main issue right now and removed the else, i want to print a message telling the user that they have entered incorrect data. where would i place the code for this such that it doesnt appear before theyve entered anything but after they have entered incorrect data?

Comment: What is getTvSeries() returning?

Comment: @JamieMcKeown as I mentioned the else part should be out of the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static String checkUserInputSeriesName(Scanner sc, SeriesLibrary seriesLibrary){
    boolean validInput = false;
    String seriesName = null;
    do{
        validInput = false;
        seriesName=sc.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < seriesLibrary.getTvSeries().size(); i++){
            if(seriesName.equals(seriesLibrary.getTvSeries().get(i))){
                validInput = true;
            }
        }  
        if(!validInput){
            System.out.println("That Series does not exist, please try again!");
            sc.nextLine();
        } 
    }while(!validInput);
    return seriesName;
}
```